# What is the expected value of a coin-toss that doubles in value if heads and why is it different in practice?

Tags: python, math, statistics, probability

Here's the thought experiment: say I have a coin that is worth 1$. Everytime I toss it, if it lands on head, it will double in value. If it lands on tail, it will be forever stuck with the latest value. What is the expected final value of the coin?

Here is how I am thinking about it:

ExpectedValue = 1 * 0.5 + (1 * 2) * (0.5 * 0.5) + (1 * 2 * 2) * (0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5) ...

=0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 ...

= Infinity

Assuming my Math is correct, the expected value should be infinity. However, when I do try to simulate it out on code, the expected value comes out very different. Here's the code below:

```
import random

def test(iterations):
    total = 0
    max = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        coin = False
        val = 1
        while coin == False:
            coin = random.choice([True, False])
            val *= 2
        total += val
        if val > max:
            max = val
    ave = total/iterations
    print(ave)

test(10000000)  # returns 38.736616
```

I assume that the sample size of 10000000 should be statistically significant enough. However, the final expected value returned is 38.736616, which is nowhere near Infinity. Either my Math is wrong or my code is wrong. Which is it?

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you describe.  For each "iteration", you start at 1, then double until you get a `True`, then stop. That's rarely going more than a few loops, so `val` is always going to be a small number.  I'm surprised it got as large as 38.  What you're doing here is counting the length of the longest "streak" of heads.  If tails is first, val is 2.  If you get heads/tails, then val is 4.  If you get heads/heads/heads/tails, then val is 16.

Comment: My code does exactly what I describe, the value starts at 1, then doubles in value for every True (head coin toss) until it reaches a False (tail)

Comment: OK, so "val", is always going to be a small power of 2.  Why do you expect infinity?  And as a side note, you will never see `val=1`.  The `while` will always run at least once, so you will always double at least once.

Comment: It is explained in the Math formula above provided above, because the expected value for each iteration always double while the probability to reach it halves, which should make the expected value a never ending addition of 0.5

Comment: But you aren't printing the SUM of the results.  You're printing the AVERAGE.  The average `val` is a small power of 2.

Comment: it was never supposed to be the sum of the results, it is meant to reach the expected value by performing the experiment many times and taking the average.

Comment: OK, and you have that.  The average will NEVER be infinite, because you will always reach a "tails" eventually, and usually rather quickly.  Your "ExpectedValue" equation is SUMMING the results, not averaging them.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this question on the stats stack exchange. I do not believe you can apply the formula for the expected value in this case.

Comment: If you think it will not be infinite, please do explain to me what is wrong in my formula

Comment: One thing I'll mention is that you end up doubling the value of the coin no matter what the result of the first flip is. You should do `while True`, flip the coin, double it if it's `True` or `break` if it's `False`

Comment: You'll only every have an infinitely valued coin if you never land on tails. If your code ever finishes executing then you know you haven't landed heads forever. In other words, your simulation is incomplete even if your math works out.

Comment: Given an infinite number of trials, you would get an infinite result.  Even the function `f(x) = 0.5`, if summed infinitely, would produce an infinite result.  That's essentially what you've described.  Use a `defaultdict` to count up the results.  In my case, I get just under 5 million 2s, 2.5 million 4s, 1.25 million 8s, 625,000 16s, and so on.  Exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: @Woodford the expected value of a random experiment is a theoretical value. There are plenty of random experiments whose expected value is not even a real outcome, most famously a coin flip, whose expected value is 1/2. The expected value of a random experiment can be derived mathematically or approximated empirically. OP is trying to reconcile the two but is failing because the theoretical expected value of this experiment I'm almost positive can't be found in the way OP posits.

Answer (score 1):

The average value of the process over infinitely many trials is infinite. However, you did not perform infinitely many trials; you only performed 10,000,000, which falls short of infinity by approximately infinity.

Suppose we have a fair coin. In four flips, the average number of heads that come up is two. So, I do 100 trials:  100 times, I flip the coin four times, and I count the heads. I got 2.11, not two. Why?

My 100 trials are only 100 samples from the population. They are not distributed the same way as the population. Your 10,000,000 trials are only 10,000,000 samples from an infinite population. None of your samples happened to include the streak of a hundred heads in a row, which would have made the value for that sample 2<sup>99</sup>, and would have made the average for your 10,000,000 trials more than 2<sup>99</sup>/10,000,000 = 6.338•10<sup>22</sup>, which is a huge number (but still not infinity).

If you increase the number of trials, you will tend to see increasing averages, because increasing the number of trials tends to move your samples toward the full population distribution. For the process you describe, you need to move infinitely far to get to the full distribution. So you need infinitely many trials.

(Also, there is a bug in your code. If the trial starts with `False`, representing tails, it still doubles the value. This means the values for 0, 1, 2, 3… heads are taken as 2, 4, 8, 16,… The process you describe in the question would have them as 1, 2, 4, 8,…)

Another way of looking at this is to conduct just one trial. The average value for just one trial is infinite. However, half the time you start one trial, you stop after one coin flip, since you got a tail immediately. One quarter of the time you stop after one or two flips. One-eighth of the time, you stop after three flips. Most of the time, you will get a small number as the answer. In **every** trial, you will get a finite number as the answer; every trial will always end with getting a tail, and the value at that point will be finite. It is impossible to do a finite number of trials and ever end up with an infinite value. Yet there is no finite number that is greater than the expected value: If you do more and more trials, the average will tend to grow and grow, and, eventually, it will exceed any finite target.

Comment: Hi @Eric, this does seem to make sense, but I did try increasing the trials from 1, to 10, to 100, all the way to 10000000, and what I have noticed is that past 10000, the the average number did not seem to further increase anymore. I understand that I can never actually have Infinity as the final average, but I thought the number would be pretty damn big given the non-trivial sample size.